# Use libraries or write my own code as a beginner?

Tags: python

I started with python a few months ago and I have several projects in mind, but what has been stopping me a lot is the fact of using libraries, because It seems to me like I'm just learning to use a library instead of improving my skills.

So... should I worry about that as a beginner?

Comment: I think you over overthinking it, just finish some projects first with any tools you have available, there is always the right tool for something, don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Knowing which libraries exist and *how to use them* is a skill in itself. `pandas` and `numpy` are fantastic  libraries for data science. `requests` is great for HTTP. `beautifulsoup` for parsing XHTML... What exactly do you need from these "several projects"?

Comment: Knowing the libraries is a good skill.

Comment: Try to solve puzzles online like www.codefights.com or similar ones!

Comment: Also, the standard library itself is huge. And you likely don't need external libraries for some things. https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: A key skill of software development is being able to use the tools available to you. If you spend all your time reinventing what others have already done you'll never accomplish your actual goals. Not only that, but Python itself is (in essence) a great big library that abstracts away any number of lower-level concerns you might otherwise have to address. You'll learn to be good at Python, programming, and software engineering by *using* the libraries, not by avoiding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using libraries, even though it may feel like "cheating" at first.

Thousands of hours of work have gone into developing high-quality libraries for Python that allow you to finish more sophisticated projects with greater ease. As some commenters have noted, there's no use in "re-inventing the wheel". At first, when you work on small simple programs, a few well-placed library function calls may compose the bulk of your code. It will take some time to learn which functions are readily available and how to use them, but this will assist you in future projects as well.

On the other hand, if there is a *concept* that you wish to better understand, it could be worth implementing yourself.

For example, in almost all contexts, implementing matrix multiplication from scratch in Python is definitely a waste of your time, since the `numpy` library provides this functionality and will perform faster than any code you write. If you're interested in **how** matrix multiplication is performed, and want to investigate more efficient algorithms for doing so, only then is it worth implementing yourself (why you would be doing this in Python is besides the point).

In short, for educational purposes, when you want to know **how** something works, you can try building it yourself. Otherwise, please, use the libraries! They are there for a reason.